# Is it possible to link progressive web app to toast

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, toast

I have code for a toast like below.

html

```
<button onclick="launch_toast()">Show Toast</button>

<div id="toast"><div id="img">Icon</div><div id="desc">A notification message..</div></div>
```

css

```
#toast {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*margin-left: -125px;*/
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;

    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;right:0;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#toast #img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    float: left;

    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;

    box-sizing: border-box;


    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
}
#toast #desc{


    color: #fff;

    padding: 16px;

    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#toast.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, expand 0.5s 0.5s,stay 3s 1s, shrink 0.5s 2s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, expand 0.5s 0.5s,stay 3s 1s, shrink 0.5s 4s, fadeout 0.5s 4.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    from {min-width: 50px} 
    to {min-width: 350px}
}

@keyframes expand {
    from {min-width: 50px}
    to {min-width: 350px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes stay {
    from {min-width: 350px} 
    to {min-width: 350px}
}

@keyframes stay {
    from {min-width: 350px}
    to {min-width: 350px}
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
    from {min-width: 350px;} 
    to {min-width: 50px;}
}

@keyframes shrink {
    from {min-width: 350px;} 
    to {min-width: 50px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 60px; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 60px; opacity: 0;}
}
```

js

```
function launch_toast() {    
  var x = document.getElementById("toast");   
  x.className = "show";    
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); 
  }, 5000); 
}
```

I want to know how to link this code to my progressive web app so that on clicking the user is able to download the PWA. My [site](http://demo.justinechacko.in).

Comment: Have you checked this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Dev-AppConsult/Progressive-Web-Apps-on-Windows-10-Live-Tiles-Toast/ba-p/317092)? It uses a pop up a native toast and show the notification in Action Center in PWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get a reference to the `beforeinstallpromt` event, on which you can call the `promt` function later on in your toast. You can get this event by adding an event listener as follows (source: [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates)):

```
let installPromptEvent;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  // Prevent Chrome <= 67 from automatically showing the prompt
  event.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  installPromptEvent = event;
  // Update the install UI to notify the user app can be installed
  document.querySelector('#install-button').disabled = false;
});
```

Hence, in your `launch_toast` function, you can launch the prompt:

```
function launch_toast(){
  installPromptEvent.prompt();
}
```

This is, of course, assuming that your manifest is configured well and that your service worker could also be registered. If the device does not support this, the `beforeinstallprompt` will not be fired and your reference to `installPromptEvent` will be `undefined`. The event will also not fire when the PWA is already installed on the device.

Comment: I think it would make sense to have this in your main.js file

Comment: Is your manifest and service worker configured correctly? Then the code from my answer should work

Comment: Why are you trying to disable the button? It seems like a separate problem. If you just leave the button the same as in your question, the code should work.

Comment: @JustineChacko Browser support can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Not that I am aware. Hopefully, the support will improve soon.

Comment: https://www.netguru.com/codestories/few-tips-that-will-make-your-pwa-on-ios-feel-like-native please go to protip 3

Comment: @JustineChacko that is not an add-home-screen popup, but rather a popup with an explanation on how to add the PWA to the home screen. Safari for iOS simply does not support ATH yet, but I think the article proposes a decent alternative for the time being.

Comment: Thank you  Works with Chrome v92.0